# Auto-creating a "link" table between 2 main tables (ex table EmployeeProject from Employee and Project tables)

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 2 tables, Medication containing: IDMedication, IDCategory, Name, and Supplier, containing: IDSupplier, Name. I want to automatically create a relationship table, MedicationSupplier, containing: IDMedication and IDSupplier as keys, Price, and Quantity.
My idea was to have a main page where i request the following data: (Medication)Name, IDCAtegory, (Supplier)Name, Price, Quantity.
I'm not sure if i'm doing the right thing here.

So this is what i'm receiveing in the .php where i do the insert:

```
$Denumire=$_POST['Denumire']; //Medication Name
$IDCategorie=$_POST['IDCategorie']; //IDCategory
$Nume=$_POST['Nume']; //Supplier Name
$Pret=$_POST['Pret']; //Price
$Stoc=$_POST['Stoc']; //Quantity
```

And this is my insert:

```
$q_produse = "INSERT INTO produse VALUES ('','$IDCategorie','$Denumire')";
$q_prodfurniz = "INSERT INTO produsfurnizor VALUES ('','$IDFurnizor','$Pret','$Stoc')";

mysql_query($q_produse) or die($error);
mysql_query($q_prodfurniz) or die($error);

mysql_close();
```

My main problem at the moment is that i don't know how to insert IDMedication in the relationship table. Any help / suggestions of improving my code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're needing to get the auto id created for the rows in your Medication and Supplier tables.  You can use `mysql_insert_id()`

```
$q_produse = "INSERT INTO produse VALUES ('','$IDCategorie','$Denumire')";
$q_prodfurniz = "INSERT INTO produsfurnizor VALUES ('','$IDFurnizor','$Pret','$Stoc')";

mysql_query($q_produse) or die($error);
$produse_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query($q_prodfurniz) or die($error);
$prodfurniz_id = mysql_insert_id();

$q_relationTable = "INSERT INTO MedicationSupplier VALUES ('$produse_id','$prodfurniz_id')";
mysql_query($q_relationTable) or die($error);

mysql_close();
```

Documentation on `mysql_insert_id()` is available at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id

retrieves the last autoincremented value, in this case, IDMedication.